# ExecutorService that rethrows exceptions

Tags: java, exception, executorservice, executor, rethrow

I need to execute a task using any `Executor` or `ExecutorService`. The task (`Callable` or `Runnable`) is supposed to run infinitely, but in case of any exception it should be rethrown to the thread that submitted the task.

I know that `future.get()` would throw `ExecutionException` for me:

```
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  Future<?> future = executor.submit(new Task());
  future.get();
```

However, in sunny day scenario I block on `future.get()` indefinitely, so I cannot use it.

Is it possible to have any `Executor` that simply throws exception when underlying task fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do this with simply using Executors.
You can consider using a try-catch block in your Task and add the exception on to a queue in the catch block.

```
try{
   //perform task
  }catch(Exception e){
     queue.offer(e)
  }
```

Create a thread that reads the exception from the queue.

```
public void run() {
        Exception e;
            try {
                    e = q.take();
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
    }
```